# Error: "Expected the reducer to be a function." when `reducer` is definitely a function

Tags: redux, react-redux

During testing, I'm getting an exception thrown:

```
Expected the reducer to be a function.
```

But it doesn't make sense. The `reducer`'s type is definitely a `function`. However, there are also some weird things happening with the output:

```
 PASS  src/App.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log src/reducers.js:8
      --- searchResultsReducer: function
    console.log src/store.js:12
      --- 6666: createStore, rootReducer: function
    console.log node_modules/redux/lib/createStore.js:54
      --- 1111 redux/lib/creatStore: typeof reducer: function
    console.log node_modules/redux/lib/createStore.js:66
      --- 5555 redux/lib/creatStore: typeof reducer: function
    console.log node_modules/redux/lib/applyMiddleware.js:38
      --- 7777 typeof reducer: function
    console.log node_modules/redux/lib/createStore.js:54
      --- 1111 redux/lib/creatStore: typeof reducer: function
    console.log node_modules/redux/lib/createStore.js:70
      --- 2222 redux/lib/creatStore: typeof reducer: function
    console.log node_modules/redux/lib/createStore.js:72
      --- 3333 redux/lib/creatStore: typeof reducer: function
    console.log node_modules/redux/lib/applyMiddleware.js:40
      --- 8888 typeof reducer: function

 FAIL  src/actions/querySelector.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Expected the reducer to be a function.

      at createStore (node_modules/redux/lib/createStore.js:77:11)
      at node_modules/redux/lib/applyMiddleware.js:39:19
      at createStore (node_modules/redux/lib/createStore.js:67:33)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store.js:13:54)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/actions/search.js:4:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/reducers/search.js:1:220)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/reducers.js:5:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/actions/querySelector.test.js:7:17)
          at <anonymous>

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.845s
Ran all test suites matching /a/.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Each one of those `console.log` lines is showing that the reducer's type is `function`. However, the `--- 4444` line never prints, but the `Error` definitely gets thrown.

Here are the `console.log` statements to the `createStore()` function:

**`node_modules/redux/lib/createStore.js`:**

```
// [... snip ...]

function createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) {
  var _ref2;

  console.log('--- 1111 redux/lib/creatStore: typeof reducer:', typeof reducer);

  if (typeof preloadedState === 'function' && typeof enhancer === 'undefined') {
    enhancer = preloadedState;
    preloadedState = undefined;
  }

  if (typeof enhancer !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof enhancer !== 'function') {
      throw new Error('Expected the enhancer to be a function.');
    }

    console.log('--- 5555 redux/lib/creatStore: typeof reducer:', typeof reducer);
    return enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState);
  }

  console.log('--- 2222 redux/lib/creatStore: typeof reducer:', typeof reducer);
  if (typeof reducer === 'function') {
    console.log('--- 3333 redux/lib/creatStore: typeof reducer:', typeof reducer);
  }

  if (typeof reducer !== 'function') {
    console.log('--- 4444 redux/lib/creatStore: typeof reducer:', typeof reducer);
    throw new Error('Expected the reducer to be a function.');
  }

// [... snip ...]
```

As you can see, by the time `--- 3333` prints that the `reducer`'s type is `function`, the comparison should result in false, and not throw the exception, but it throws the exception anyway, and doesn't even print the `--- 4444` output line.

What is happening to the `console.log` statements, and why is the reducer's type not being properly detected?

Here is the rest of the code:

**`src/App.test.js`:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    div
  );
});
```

**`src/actions/querySelector.test.js`:**

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

import * as actions from './querySelector';
import * as types from './querySelector';
import { rootReducer } from '../reducers';

describe('actions', () => {

  it('should select a query', () => {
    expect(1).equalTo(1);
  });
});
```

**`src/reducers.js`:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { chartsReducer } from './reducers/charts';
import { errorsReducer } from './reducers/errors';
import { searchResultsReducer } from './reducers/search';
import { querySelectorReducer } from './reducers/querySelector';

console.log('--- searchResultsReducer:', typeof searchResultsReducer);

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  charts: chartsReducer,
  errors: errorsReducer,
  search: searchResultsReducer,
  querySelector: querySelectorReducer,
});
```

**`src/reducers/querySelector.js`:**

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

export const querySelectorReducer = (state = {queries: Map()}, action) => {
  return state;
}
```

**`src/components/QuerySelector.js`:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ImmutablePropTypes from 'react-immutable-proptypes';

class QuerySelector extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    queries: ImmutablePropTypes.map.isRequired,
    onSelectQuery: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onClickManage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    return (<div/>);
  }
}

export default QuerySelector;
```

**`src/containers/QuerySelectorRedux.js`:**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import QuerySelector from '../components/QuerySelector';

import {
  selectQuery,
  manageQueries,
} from '../actions/querySelector';

export const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    queries: state.querySelector.queries,
  };
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSelectQuery: id => {
      dispatch(selectQuery(id));
    },
    onClickManage: () => {
      dispatch(manageQueries());
    },
  };
};

const QuerySelectorRedux = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(QuerySelector);

export default QuerySelectorRedux;
```

Comment: At a quick glance, are all reducers `formReducer`? If not, you might need deep modal.

Comment: I got rid of all forms and it's the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It was because my test script was importing the `rootReducer`.